# Leaflet custom marks json

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

why can't i get my custom marks icon to work? I've tried out lots of things. It worked before. It keeps showing the standard blue one no matter what i do.

```
 var my_json;

  var map = L.map('map').setView([54.914345, 9.803561], 15);
  
  
  
  
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  var smallIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: 'car.png',
    iconRetinaUrl: 'carx2.png',
    iconSize:    [25, 41],
    iconAnchor:  [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize:  [41, 41]
  });

  
      // create an empty L.GeoJSON layer
    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
    
    function requestGeoJson(){
        fetch('results.geojson?' + (new Date()).getTime())
          .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
          .then(function(json){ 
             geoJsonLayer.clearLayers().addData(json);
    
             setTimeout(requestGeoJson, 5000);
          });
    };
    requestGeoJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the icon to the marker in the `pointToLayer` function of `L.geoJSON()`:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson({
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {icon: smallIcon});
    },
}).addTo(map);
```

if this is not working you need to check the icon-url

Comment: I tried it and the url for the icon is right i checked it and also change tried to change it too the full path if i do as you said it just removes every point on the map